# Angular: Custom validator returning null makes Angular throw an error

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, custom-validators

When I try to return null while validating a FormControlObject the browser says that it can not read the property of [FormControlObject].errors.errorProperty because its null. Am I missing here something? If I return  { errorProperty: false } it all works.

The code:

```
    static passwordsShouldMatch(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
  let newPassword = control.get('password');
  let repeatedPassword = control.get('repeatedPassword');

  if (newPassword.value !== repeatedPassword.value) {
    return { passwordsShouldMatch: true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

SOLUTION:

```
    static passwordsShouldMatch(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
  let newPassword = control.get('password');
  let repeatedPassword = control.get('repeatedPassword');

  if (newPassword.value !== repeatedPassword.value) {
    return { passwordsShouldMatch: true };
  }
  return {passwordsShouldMatch: false};
}
```

I have commented out the solution to this problem, but following the documentation, you should be able to return null without a problem. This question might be a duplicate to this   [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199523/returning-null-in-angular-2-custom-validator-throwing-an-error), but since that was asked 9 months ago and also did not resolve this potential problem I think it is ok to ask again.

Problem reproduced: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d5utxs

Comment: Post a completeminimal example, in a StackBlitz or plunkr, reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet Of course, here is a stripped down version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d5utxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
account.errors.passwordsShouldMatch
```

by

```
account.hasError('passwordsShouldMatch')
```

As you can see in [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#errors), the type of `FormGroup.errors` is `ValidationErrors | null`.